# How to find a non-exact ODE which becomes exact for a given integrating factor?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, integrating-factor

Do you have any non-exact differential equation example for the integrating factor $x + y$? I couldn't find any books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the differential equation

$$\frac{1}{x + y} + \frac{2}{x + y} y' = 0.$$

This equation is not exact, but if you use the integrating factor $\mu = x + y$, you obtain the exact differential equation

$$1 + 2y' = 0.$$